# How to differentiate Nekomimi from Inumimi?

Tags: terminology

So, how to differentiate Nekomimi from Inumimi? They looks quite similar.

Comment: Look at the tail.

Comment: This isn't efficient for every character since some of them don't have tails. Kuraishi Tanpopo for example has no tail, but her mannerisms make it obvious that she has nekomimi.

Comment: @kobato-tan Yeah, there are some characters where you absolutely can't tell until someone else comes along and says "Oh, what a cute kitty!" or something, but that wasn't nearly as pithy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both words can be summerized with *Kemonomimi* (獣耳) what just means animal ears.

> Kemonomimi, literally meaning "animal ears", is the concept of drawing
>   animals as bishōjo or bishōnen, or having such characters wear animal
>   accessories such as ears or tails. Catgirls and catboys are the most
>   prolific in this category, although bunnygirls, foxgirls, and dog
>   girls are also common. Kemonomimi characters typically appear human
>   except for added animal-like qualities.

<sub>Quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_anthropomorphism#Animals).</sub>

**Nekomimi** and **Inumimi** are some more accurate designation for such designed characters. But there is one essential difference.

The word **Nekomimi** (猫耳) means "*cat-ears*" in english. On the other hand you have the word **Inumimi** (犬耳) what means "*dog-ears*". And this is pretty much the difference... **Nekomimi** are styled like cats and **Inumimi** are styled like dogs.

Traditionally they only wear a headband with the ears of the animal they dress up without a tail or paws.

On this picture you are able to clearly see the difference between this two species. Left a Neko and right a Inu styled girl.

[image: Ears]

<sub>Picture from the [nonoshirip blog](http://nonoshirip.blog73.fc2.com/blog-entry-45.html).</sub>

It is not always that easy to find out what is shown at the moment because there are also some **Inumimi** with pointed ears. But you are also able to recognize them apart by the tail.

As before, **Nekomimi** have a tail like the tail of a cat. **Inumimi** more like a dog. Here is a picture with the tail. Again left the Neko and right the Inu styled girl.

[image: Tail]

<sub>Left picture from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/1773005) and right picture from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/1750563).</sub>

Sometimes it is very hard to recognize them apart only by the ears. If you really want to know who is who you need more characteristics than only the ears.

But watch out! There are *Kemonomimi* that look similar to the cat or even more the dog... A example are Kitsunemimi (狐耳) what means "fox-ears" or Okamimimi (狼耳) what means "wolf-ears".

[image: Kitsu and Okami]

<sub>Left image from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/1320423) and right image from [ZeroChan](http://www.zerochan.net/239366).</sub>

You could guess who is who? Left is the fox styled girl and right is the wolf girl. And this is a example where it is actully very hard to find out what *Kemonomimi* style the character is designed.

Comment: And then there are kitsunemimi (fox ears), which can look very much like either, though they are usually slightly thinner / longer and point "upwards".

Comment: What about the case where the cat is based on expensive cats, like Persian cats, whose tails are like that of dogs?

Comment: @TendouKishi It is very hard if you see such a character. You can't really because they nearly look the same...